# How to get the actual hard link URLs

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing research on a subject. The sites which are developed in javascript for eg. https://hp.taleo.net/careersection/2/jobsearch.ftl# . If we click on the paging, the URL doesn't change and yet the contents of the page are changed. Whether there are some variables which are getting submitted and if yes then what are these variables. What would one have  to do if one wants the actual hard link the next page for this site or the similar sites. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The page using ajax, if you you use Chrome you can see with Developer Tools, if you can use Firefox you can use Firebug plug-in for better understanding what is going on behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hard URLs... The site is loading it dynamically through ajax.

Inspect the website using Firefox or Chrome/Safari Dev Tools. Open the network tab and submit the form.

[Network Tab](http://d.saew.it/XSwb)

As you can see, it's posting the data to that page. Do some investigation and see what you come up with.

You can also try turning off javascript and seeing if it falls back to hard urls.